# How to put data from 3 external CSVs into arrays (Got the first 2 working, 3rd not)

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv

I am attempting to get data from 3 separate CSVs and put the data into 3 separate arrays, in the code below the first 2 work fine, the third which is a clone of the second one with a few details changed doesn't... why?

How can I do get the third working too?

```
    // First one

    $awd_fp = fopen( 'https://example.com/test1.csv', 'r' );

    $awd_stocks_temp = array();

    while( $awd_row = fgetcsv( $awd_fp ) ) {
        $awd_stocks_temp[] = $awd_row;
    }

    fclose( $awd_fp );

    // Second one

    $aeo_fp = fopen( 'https://example.com/test2.csv', 'r' );

    $aeo_stocks_temp = array();

    while( $aeo_row = fgetcsv( $aeo_fp ) ) {
        $aeo_stocks_temp[] = $aeo_row;
    }

    fclose( $aeo_fp );

    // Third one

    $hb_fp = fopen( 'https://example.com/test3.csv', 'r' );

    $hb_stocks_temp = array();

    while( $hb_row = fgetcsv( $hb_fp ) ) {
        $hb_stocks_temp[] = $hb_row;
    }

    fclose( $hb_fp );

    echo '<hr>';
    echo count( $awd_stocks_temp ) . ' / ';
    echo count( $aeo_stocks_temp ) . '/ ';
    echo count( $hb_stocks_temp );
    echo '<hr>';
```

Comment: Have you checked what you are getting back from `test3.csv`. Code looks OK, so it must be the data

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the csv file. Did you check if it returns any error?

Comment: If I `print_r` the array I am trying to make it is empty. If I load the file in the browser it downloads and has the data included (works exactly the same as the second file)

Comment: I have changed the last request to be hosted elsewhere and it works, therefore I think the 3rd request from my question maybe being blocked, although it is hosted on the same host as the 2nd which works...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine it seems something's wrong with your csv file. Only thing I would suggest is instead of writing same code for reading csv file why don't you loop through it.

```
<?php
$files = array(
    'test1.csv',
    'test2.csv',
    'test3.csv'
);
$stocks_temp = array();
$ctr = 0;
foreach($files as $file){
    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );
    while( $row = fgetcsv( $fp ) ) {
        $stocks_temp[$ctr][] = $row;
    }
    fclose( $fp );
    $ctr++;
}

// you will get all data in multidimensional array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($stocks_temp);
?>
```